# Problems upgrading jquery 1.4.2 to 1.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to upgrade from jquery 1.4.2 to 1.5.1 and I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [rel*=address:]

I can't figure out what it's related to.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

attribute selector needs to be enclosed by quote `"`

i.e. `[rel*="address:"]`

Comment: This was it.  it was actually a bug in another plugin that i was including that had the missing quotes.

Comment: jQuery address plugin 1.0 had this problem.  By version 1.4, the problem has been solved.  http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to escape the colon in the attribute:

If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \. For example, if you have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Earlier versions of jquery seemed to be more forgiving

Answer (score 1):

It may be that jQuery 1.4.2 *just so happened* to accept your invalid expression, but [the correct expression is](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
[rel*="address:"]
```

This is why it's very important that you read the documentation and use the *correct* syntax, regardless of whether or not your broken code "appears to work".